# Pointers confusion

Tags: c++, pointers

I'm confused about how pointers work here. I have a class called `PrefixTree` and a struct called `TreeNode` within this class. I have the following code to build a tree with a string, the problem is every time `preorder()` is called it doesn't return the root character correctly and after that it throws a segmentation fault.

I want to know if I'm correctly setting the `root` pointer or if I'm misusing it in the others files.

```
//prefixtree.cpp
PrefixTree::TreeNode* PrefixTree::buildTree(string& input)
{
  char c = input[0];
  input.erase(0,1);

  TreeNode* node = new TreeNode();
  node->character = c;

  if (!root)
    root = node;

  if (c == '*')
  {
    node->left  = buildTree(input);
    node->right = buildTree(input);
  }

  return node;
}

void PrefixTree::preorder()
{
  traverse(root);
}

void PrefixTree::traverse(TreeNode* node)
{
  if (node)
  {
    cout << node->character << endl;
    traverse(node->left);
    traverse(node->right);
  }
}
```

and

```
//prefixtree.h

class PrefixTree
{
  private:
    struct TreeNode 
    { 
      char character; 
      TreeNode* left; 
      TreeNode* right; 
    };

    TreeNode* root; 

    void traverse(TreeNode* node);

  public:
    TreeNode* buildTree(string& input);
    void preorder();
};
```

and

```
//main.cpp
PrefixTree tree;
string a = string("*a**!*dc*rb");
cout << tree.buildTree(a)->character << endl;

tree.preorder();
```

Comment: Looks ok at a glance.

Comment: If you think preorder has a bug, please provide the code

Comment: I've just provided the whole code

Comment: Your `buildTree()` function must check if the input is a null string at the start of the function and must return as soon as it is empty.

Comment: Add line `if (input.empty()) return;` as the first line of your function `buildTree()`.

Comment: if (!root)
    root = node; //root is uninitialized, why check for value?

Comment: `if (input.empty()) return NULL;` does not change anything on the program's output

Comment: @AndrásKovács I need to know whether the root was initialized due to be the initial pointer for the other tree nodes.

Comment: It looks like it builds the tree right. The problem is the `root` pointer isn't pointing to the start of the tree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to initialize the pointer members, they are not automatically initialized and may contain garbage values instead of `nullptr`, which leads to your tests `if(!root)` and `if(node)` being useless, reporting uninitialized pointers as valid, which you will then dereference.

Add constructors:

```
class PrefixTree
{
private:
    struct TreeNode 
    { 
        char character; 
        TreeNode* left; 
        TreeNode* right;

        TreeNode() : character('a'), left(nullptr), right(nullptr) {};
    };

    TreeNode* root; 

    void traverse(TreeNode* node);

public:
    PrefixTree() : root(nullptr) {};

    TreeNode* buildTree(string& input);
    void preorder();
};
```

Comment: What if I want to start with a `NULL` root?

Comment: @waldyr.ar What do you mean? `nullptr` is basically equivalent to `NULL` here.

Comment: I don't want a character `'a'` on my root. It should be a `NULL` pointer to be initialized with the first char of `input` in `buildTree`

Comment: Ah ok, that was just an example, write whatever you want, you will overwrite `character` anyway in `buildTree`. The constructor does not replace the logic of `buildTree`. It just guarantees that `root`, `left` and `right` are `NULL` before they are used.

Comment: I'm still getting segmentation fault

Comment: I'm at OSX using g++ and my output is the following: ./a.out 
*
?
[1]    4587 segmentation fault  ./a.out

Comment: @waldyr.ar Can you please use a debugger to find the line throwing the segmentation fault? I don't see any other problem with the code right now.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't see the prefixtree constructor. It was the missing part, only it :)